# How to specify width of a tooltip in Bootstrap 2

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html code with bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text">
        <span class="add-on">
        <a rel="tooltip" data-original-title="this is the tooltip text but it's too long to display" href="#">
            <i class="icon red icon-remove-sign"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

And in my script.js file i have $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();, which is also a bootstrap feature.
The problem is, when the tooltip is displayed only a part of the title is displayed. How can I set the width of a tooltip in bootstrap?

Comment: Please make a Fiddle.

Comment: I made the fiddle, but strangely it looks normal here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mistily/4B28K/1/). Anyhow I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The input-append class has a `whitespace:nowrap` attribute. If I remove that, it appears normally.

Answer (score 1):

Give a Class to `<a>` Tag say

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="tool"><i class="icon"></i></a>

.tool{ // stuffs}
```

OR

Create a `<div>`inside that give the`<a rel="tooltip">` and give seperate class to the `<div>`